# How to find anything by query in blender (not F3)

Tags: documentation

How do I find the checkbox for denoising (cycles) by searching for `denois`.

The manual [0] is no help, I can't see

```
Render Layers ‣ Denoising
```

[0] https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html

Comment: Hello, could you expand a little bit on what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: in 2.91 there is a new feature **Display Filter** . in properties and outliner you can find stuff with ctrl+f and alt+f for clearing search

Comment: @mma78 Post as answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new feature in 2.91 Display Filter or Property Search allows you to ctrl+f to find things and alt+f to clear search field
[link](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/User_Interface)

[image]